# How to make UIImage shown as the size of the UIView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, cgrectmake

```
UIImage *image = (UIImage *) [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f ", (image.size.width/9), (image.size.height/16), (568/image.size.height), (round((568/image.size.height) * image.size.width)));
if((image.size.width/9)<(image.size.height/16)){
    imageLoad.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, round((320/image.size.height) * image.size.height));
}
else if((image.size.width/9)>(image.size.height/16)){
    imageLoad.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, round((568/image.size.height) * image.size.width), 568);
}
else{
    imageLoad.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, round((568/image.size.height) * image.size.width), 568);
}
NSLog(@"%f %f", imageLoad.frame.size.width, imageLoad.frame.size.height);
imageLoad.hidden = NO;
imageLoad.image = image;
```

I changed the size of the `UIImageView *imageLoad` using `CGRectMake`, and I thought `UIImage *image` will be shown as the size of the `UIImageView *imageLoad`. However, it didn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// this means your image is fit in to your view size
imageLoad.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imageLoad.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
```

Comment: The content mode determine how a view lays out its content when its bounds change. https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode